# PHP - cURL Get response body

Tags: php, curl

How can I print the response content from an URL because preview is empty

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Picture:

[image]

Comment: @AliTrixx isn't working... the output isn't the same with response

Comment: When debugging any kind of coding issue, turn error reporting on. Your code provided should have thrown an error since your missing a single quote before the name of your cookie file. As someone else answered, echo the $output to print the result on the page.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to echo out the response so

   ```
   echo $output;
   ```
2. I noticed that you are missing single quotes around the name of your cookie file and cookie jar.. they should become

   ```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
   ```